# PHP "if statements" performance issues

Tags: php, performance, if-statement

I'm trying to improve performance in my script.

I have a massive (PHP)array who contains 3543 lines.

I'm outputing this in a (HTML)table.

For each line(TR) the script takes 0.003 seconds. As I have 3543 records it takes : 3543 * 0.003 seconds = 10.6 seconds <-- that is not ok.
Please help me improving this :

```
foreach ($this->m_data as $value) {
    ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $value['nom'] ?> <?php echo $value['prenom'] ?> <?php $time_start_line = microtime(true); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo dateToFR($value['ddn']) ?></td>
    <td>
        <span class="<?php echo $visite['type_raw'] ?>">
            <?php if (!isset($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0])) : ?>
                <a href="?page=visiteSuivi1&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" class="">[ Ajouter une visite ]</a>
            <?php else : ?>
                <a href="?page=visiteSuivi2&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" class="">[ Ajouter une visite ]</a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php if (!isset($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0])) : ?>
            <a href="?page=visiteIdentification&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">[ <?php echo dateTimeToDateFR($value['date']) ?> ]</a>
        <?php elseif (isset($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]) && !isset($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][0])): ?>
            <a href="?page=visiteSuivi1&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>&vid=<?php echo $value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]['id'] ?>" class="">[ <?php echo dateToFr($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]['dateVisite']) ?> ]</a>

        <?php elseif (isset($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][0]) && count($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']])): ?>
            <a href="?page=visiteSuivi2&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>&vid=<?php echo $value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][count($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']]) - 1]['id'] ?>" class="">[ <?php echo dateToFr($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][count($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']]) - 1]['dateVisite']) ?> ]</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="?page=visiteIdentification&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">[ <?php echo dateTimeToDateFR($value['date']) ?> ]</a>
    </td>
    <td class="datatable_row_detail" style="display:none">

        <div class="row">
            <!-- Visite Identification -->
            <div class="columns large-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns large-4"><span class="itemDetail"><?php echo dateTimeToDateFR($value['date']) ?> </span></div>
                    <div class="columns large-4"> <a class="itemDetail" href="?page=visiteIdentification&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">[ Visite Identification ]</a></div>
                    <div class="columns large-4"><a class="itemDetail" href="#">[ Version PDF ]</a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Visite suivie 1 -->
            <?php if (isset($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0])): ?>
                <div class="columns large-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="columns large-4"><span class="itemDetail"><?php echo dateToFr($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]['dateVisite']) ?></span></div>
                        <div class="columns large-4"><a class="itemDetail" href="?page=visiteSuivi1&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>&vid=<?php echo $value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]['id'] ?>" >[ Visite <?php echo $oms_visites[0]['display-name'] ?> ]</a></div>
                        <div class="columns large-4"><a class="itemDetail" href="#">[ Version PDF ]</a> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!-- Visite suivie 2 -->
            <?php if (isset($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][0])): ?>
                <?php foreach ($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']] as $key => $value_v) : ?>


                    <div class="columns large-12">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="columns large-4"><span class="itemDetail"><?php echo dateToFr($value_v['dateVisite']) ?></span></div>
                            <div class="columns large-4"><a class="itemDetail" href="?page=visiteSuivi2&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>&vid=<?php echo $value_v['id'] ?>" >[ Visite Suivie <?php echo $key + 2 ?> ]</a></div>
                            <div class="columns large-4"><a class="itemDetail" href="#">[ Version PDF ]</a> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php
            $time_end = microtime(true);
            $time = $time_end - $time_start_line;
            echo "$time secondes\n";
            ?>
        </div>

    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

After some testing I find out that this is taking 0.004 seconds

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $value['nom'] ?> <?php echo $value['prenom'] ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo ($value['ddn']) ?></td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td class="datatable_row_detail" style="display:none">

        <div class="row">
            <!-- Visite Identification -->
            <div class="columns large-12">
                <div class="row">

                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is taking 4 seconds the only difference is two more echos  :

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $value['nom'] ?> <?php echo $value['prenom'] ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo ($value['ddn']) ?></td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="?page=visiteIdentification&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">[ <?php echo ($value['date']) ?> ]</a>
    </td>
    <td class="datatable_row_detail" style="display:none">

        <div class="row">
            <!-- Visite Identification -->
            <div class="columns large-12">
                <div class="row">

                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Now I'm wondering if I use a PHP string to concat the TRs and do just one echo will it be faster ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too open-ended; we are not a magical code speed-up service.

Comment: You might wanna read [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/optimizing-code-using-stack-overflow).

Comment: My eyes are bleeding... Seriously though, use XHProf and try to determine what exactly makes your script so slow.

Comment: I need a reason why php is taking this long in order to work with only few than 4000 lines. If statements shouldn't have this kind of performance issues.

Comment: @Su4p we cannot speculate that it's the `if` statement or a given `echo` without solid data such as XHProf output.

Comment: damn XHProf extension is not installed on my server :(

Comment: Can't you test locally?

Comment: I'm looking for a way

Comment: I'm not quite sure the question is off-topic look at the last answer. I'm pretty sure it was a code problem. The aim wasn't to optimize my code but to solve a performance issue at 11 seconds for displaying one page it's not about a optimazing but a solving a disfunctional code. Thank's to @mingos you were very helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I succeeded ! I passed from 11 seconds to 0.04 seconds ! And I discovered why :

Doing this :

```
    foreach ($this->m_data as $value) {
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value['nom'] ?> <?php echo $value['prenom'] ?> <?php $time_start_line = microtime(true); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo dateToFR($value['ddn']) ?></td>
        <td>
            <span class="<?php echo $visite['type_raw'] ?>">
                <?php if (!isset($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0])) : ?>
                    <a href="?page=visiteSuivi1&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" class="">[ Ajouter une visite ]</a>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <a href="?page=visiteSuivi2&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" class="">[ Ajouter une visite ]</a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php if (!isset($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0])) : ?>
                <a href="?page=visiteIdentification&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">[ <?php echo dateTimeToDateFR($value['date']) ?> ]</a>
            <?php elseif (isset($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]) && !isset($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][0])): ?>
                <a href="?page=visiteSuivi1&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>&vid=<?php echo $value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]['id'] ?>" class="">[ <?php echo dateToFr($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]['dateVisite']) ?> ]</a>

            <?php elseif (isset($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][0]) && count($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']])): ?>
                <a href="?page=visiteSuivi2&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>&vid=<?php echo $value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][count($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']]) - 1]['id'] ?>" class="">[ <?php echo dateToFr($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][count($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']]) - 1]['dateVisite']) ?> ]</a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="?page=visiteIdentification&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">[ <?php echo dateTimeToDateFR($value['date']) ?> ]</a>
        </td>
        <td class="datatable_row_detail" style="display:none">

            <div class="row">
                <!-- Visite Identification -->
                <div class="columns large-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="columns large-4"><span class="itemDetail"><?php echo dateTimeToDateFR($value['date']) ?> </span></div>
                        <div class="columns large-4"> <a class="itemDetail" href="?page=visiteIdentification&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>">[ Visite Identification ]</a></div>
                        <div class="columns large-4"><a class="itemDetail" href="#">[ Version PDF ]</a> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Visite suivie 1 -->
                <?php if (isset($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0])): ?>
                    <div class="columns large-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="columns large-4"><span class="itemDetail"><?php echo dateToFr($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]['dateVisite']) ?></span></div>
                            <div class="columns large-4"><a class="itemDetail" href="?page=visiteSuivi1&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>&vid=<?php echo $value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]['id'] ?>" >[ Visite <?php echo $oms_visites[0]['display-name'] ?> ]</a></div>
                            <div class="columns large-4"><a class="itemDetail" href="#">[ Version PDF ]</a> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- Visite suivie 2 -->
                <?php if (isset($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][0])): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']] as $key => $value_v) : ?>


                        <div class="columns large-12">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="columns large-4"><span class="itemDetail"><?php echo dateToFr($value_v['dateVisite']) ?></span></div>
                                <div class="columns large-4"><a class="itemDetail" href="?page=visiteSuivi2&pid=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>&vid=<?php echo $value_v['id'] ?>" >[ Visite Suivie <?php echo $key + 2 ?> ]</a></div>
                                <div class="columns large-4"><a class="itemDetail" href="#">[ Version PDF ]</a> </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php
                $time_end = microtime(true);
                $time = $time_end - $time_start_line;
                echo "$time secondes\n";
                ?>
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
```

Is cost effective in term of performance for large amount of datas. with this :

```
foreach ($this->m_data as $value) {
                        $outputTR .= '<tr>';
                        $outputTR .= '<td>' . $value['nom'] . ' ' . $value['prenom'] . '</td>';
                        $outputTR .= '<td>' . dateToFR($value['ddn']) . '</td>';
                        $outputTR .= '<td><span>';
                        if (!isset($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0])) {
                            $outputTR.='<a href="?page=visiteSuivi1&pid=' . $value['id'] . '">[ Ajouter une visite ]</a>';
                        } else {
                            $outputTR.='<a href="?page=visiteSuivi2&pid=' . $value['id'] . '">[ Ajouter une visite ]</a>';
                        }
                        $outputTR .= '</span> </td>';

                        $outputTR .= '<td>';

                        if (!isset($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0])) {
                            $outputTR .= '<a href="?page=visiteIdentification&pid=' . $value['id'] . '"> [' . dateTimeToDateFR($value['date']) . ']</a>';
                        } elseif (isset($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]) && !isset($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][0])) {
                            $outputTR .= '<a href="?page=visiteSuivi1&pid=' . $value['id'] . '&vid=' . $value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]['id'] . '"> [' . dateToFR($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]['dateVisite']) . ']</a>';
                        } elseif (isset($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][0]) && count($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']])) {
                            $outputTR .= '<a href="?page=visiteSuivi2&pid=' . $value['id'] . '&vid=' . $value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][count($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']]) - 1]['id'] . '"> [' . dateToFR($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][count($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']]) - 1]['dateVisite']) . ']</a>';
                        }

                        $outputTR .='</td>';
                        $outputTR .= '<td>';
                        $outputTR .= '<a href="?page=visiteIdentification&pid=' . $value['id'] . '">[' . dateTimeToDateFR($value['date']) . ']</a>';
                        $outputTR .= '</td>';
                        $outputTR .= '<td class="datatable_row_detail" style="display:none">';
                        $outputTR .= '<div class="row">';
                        $outputTR .= '<div class="columns large-12">';
                        $outputTR .= '<div class="row">';
                        $outputTR .= '<div class="columns large-4"><span class="itemDetail">' . dateTimeToDateFR($value['date']) . '</span></div>';
                        $outputTR .= '<div class="columns large-4"> <a class="itemDetail" href="?page=visiteIdentification&pid=' . $value['id'] . '">[ Visite Identification ]</a></div>';
                        $outputTR .= '<div class="columns large-4"><a class="itemDetail" href="#">[ Version PDF ]</a> </div>';
                        $outputTR .= '</div>';
                        $outputTR .= '</div>';
                        if (isset($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0])) {
                            $outputTR .= '<div class="columns large-12">';
                            $outputTR .= '<div class="row">';
                            $outputTR .= '<div class="columns large-4"><span class="itemDetail">' . dateToFr($value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]['dateVisite']) . '</span></div>';
                            $outputTR .= '<div class="columns large-4"> <a class="itemDetail" href="?page=visiteSuivi1&pid=' . $value['id'] . '&vid=' . $value[$oms_visites[0]['display-name']][0]['id'] . '">[ Visite Suivie 1 ]</a></div>';
                            $outputTR .= '<div class="columns large-4"><a class="itemDetail" href="#">[ Version PDF ]</a> </div>';
                            $outputTR .= '</div>';
                            $outputTR .= '</div>';
                        }
                        if (isset($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']][0])) {
                            foreach ($value[$oms_visites[1]['display-name']] as $key => $value_v) {
                                $outputTR .= '<div class="columns large-12">';
                                $outputTR .= '<div class="row">';
                                $outputTR .= '<div class="columns large-4"><span class="itemDetail">' . dateToFr($value_v['dateVisite']) . '</span></div>';
                                $outputTR .= '<div class="columns large-4"> <a class="itemDetail" href="?page=visiteSuivi2&pid=' . $value['id'] . '&vid=' . $value_v['id'] . '">[ Visite Suivie ' . ($key + 2) . ' ]</a></div>';
                                $outputTR .= '<div class="columns large-4"><a class="itemDetail" href="#">[ Version PDF ]</a> </div>';
                                $outputTR .= '</div>';
                                $outputTR .= '</div>';
                            }
                        }

                        $outputTR .='</div>';
                        $outputTR .='</td>';
                        $outputTR .= '</tr>';
                    }
                    echo $outputTR;
```

I personnaly hate puting html code inside of PHP code but in term of performance the result is spectacular.
I passed from 0.032 second/line to 2.3 exp -5 second/line. I'm not quite sure if the problem is around then open tags and close tags or is it about the multiple echos.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you split the huge data into pages. You can also lazy load the pages so it shows as a single page. No one can see all data at once.

Comment: I'm using pagination from client side. What I do not understand is why it's taking this long from the php side

Comment: data should be paged on server side also. LIMIT statement can be used to page database tables. if you have that amount of data, it should be stored in a database table. you can insert the array in a database table.

Comment: The problem is not the query itself. The query takes 0.0003 seconds for all the datas. The problem is in the <tr>.

Comment: if you process 100 records at a time, it will be completed in 0.3 seconds.

Comment: But it won't solve my performance issue it'll just hide it. It's not normal that this operation is taking this amount of time.

Comment: Paging is precisely used for that: mitigate/hide the perf issue, not optimise code.

Comment: And again that's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to solve my perf issues.

Comment: however fast PHP is, there are always limits. you have simple functions in your code like isset etc. The only functions, I don't know are dateToFR(), dateTimeToFR(). I cannot help more.

Comment: I removed dateToFR(), dateTimeToFR() and I gained 0.06 seconds on 7 seconds. Thoses doesnt seem to be the issue.

Comment: you can cache the page to static html and serve html instead of php. processing data always takes time.

Comment: Trust me, if I could I would

Comment: this place is not for solving the problems of individuals. These are the general methods for overcoming performance issues; paging and caching. if you have an exceptional installation that does not permit these, no one can help you.

Comment: I solved it see below for a general method for overcoming performance issue. There is nothing to be ashamed or pissed off about not knowing the answer ;).

Comment: well done! IMO it is still not faster than caching and you will end up with unmanageble code mixed with HTML. This was my last comment :)